# Phone application getting credit card information will pass PCI scan?

Tags: android, pci-compliance

I'm building an app to collect payments. I need to get the credit card information from the user, and then using AJAX (to a SSL url) send that info to the website. The website itself does not stores the credit card info, and neither does the phone application. Assuming that the website is PCI compliant, could the app be considered a security risk? Would it pass a PCI scan, if there is a PCI scan for apps?

Answer (score 0):

As you can't really PCI scan people's web browsers (nor phones), so those wouldn't be scanned.

However, if your website is acting as a middle man or passing card data along else where, or is in some way connected to the app (which it very likely is, login validation etc) then it would be in scope of PCI and would need a PCI Scan.